# Heroku web.1 didn't updated env variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, adonis.js

After heroku changed my database connection (db, user, host, password) I have set the new setting on my heroku configs var but when I run the application it stills try to connect to the database with the old credentials, I have checked with heroku cofig with heroku config -a app_name and this shows the new password but when I send a request to my server it says:

error: password authentication failed for user "qzmxbgddsnhdbw"

and user "qzmxbgddsnhdbw" is the old one, the new is different, running heroku config -a myappname shows:

DB_USER:        fspdcwvfirvilu

what i have tried:

- restarted app with heroku restart
- killed web.1 process with heroku ps:kill web.1
- manual deploy

Comment: "After heroku changed my database connection (db, user, host, password) I have set the new setting on my heroku configs var"—why are you changing anything? Heroku changes `DATABASE_URL` for you. If you use this value _directly_ you shouldn't have any problems connecting.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your database connection code.

Comment: I don't user DATABASE_URL for connection, I use DB_HOST, DB_USER etc, I also have changed all these env vars

Comment: It is _much_ better to use `DATABASE_URL` directly. Every time Heroku changes your connection information (which can happen at any time, without notice), your `DATABASE_URL` will automatically be updated and your application will automatically be restarted. Using `DATABASE_URL` means your application will continue to work without you having to take any action. (The value of that environment variable will be a URI, so it's quite easy to parse the value and extract individual host, user, etc. values if you really want to, but most database libraries are fine connecting via URI.)

Comment: (It would still be helpful for you to edit your database connection code into your question as I requested earlier. Assuming you're looking at the same Heroku app in both cases, the only way your environment variables and runtime configuration can be different is if the config is not properly loaded from the environment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going on, the adonis migrate command sometimes doesn't finish if there's an active connection to your database it's up to us finish the migration command, that's why the deploy got stuck it was infinitely waiting for the migration command to finish and it never finishes, it was my last command on my profile, after removing the migrate command it worked fine and everything got updated as expected